# R cellsize and read.asciigrid

Tags: r, ascii

I am new to spatial analysis and so I might have a silly question.

My problem is that I am using `read.asciigrid()` to read in a large ascii file.

When I try the function fails because it says `object 'cellsize' not found`.

My problem is that I know that there is a cellsize object in the files header, as it has the layout:

```
ncols        
nrows         
xllcorner     
yllcorner     
cellsize      
NODATA_value
```

I am not sure what the problem is, is there a way of getting around this 'missing' object or could possibly narrow down where the problem might be on my end?

Comment: There needs to be a value associated with each element in the header. Based on the information you provided one cannot tell if there is a value associated with cellsize.

Comment: there is it has a cellsize of 100

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either using readGDAL() in the rgdal package or raster() in the raster package. The readGDAL funciton will return an sp object whereas raster will return a raster object. For the most part if you are wanting to conduct raster analysis in R you want to use the raster package because it is memory safe and has many useful functions for overlay and focal analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that the .asc files I was trying to use had a leading space before all the header object names like:

```
 cellsize xxxx
 NODATA_value xxxx
```

instead of

```
cellsize xxxx
NODATA_value xxxx
```

Hopefully this is your problem, as you can simply delete the spaces in the asc file using a text editor.